# Jenkins not working after upgrade to play 2.3

Tags: java, jenkins, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I upgraded to play 2.3 recently, when I configured Jenkins I had to set it up this way with play 2.2.x so that it worked.

`play.Project.playJavaSettings
sbt.Keys.fork in Test := false
parallelExecution in Test := false`

In play 2.3 I use the following configuration

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).settings(
parallelExecution in Test := false,
fork in Test := false)

parallelExecution in Test := false

sbt.Keys.fork in Test := false
```

I have tried many variations but I cannot get it to work, the tests run fine locally but not on jenkins exception is always

```
>     [warn] play -  Error stopping plugin java.lang.NullPointerException: null     at
> play.libs.ws.ning.NingWSPlugin.onStop(NingWSPlugin.java:31)
> ~[play-java-ws_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> play.api.Play$$anonfun$stop$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(Play.scala:108)
> [play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
> play.api.Play$$anonfun$stop$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(Play.scala:107)
> [play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
> scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
> [scala-library.jar:0.13.7]    at
> play.api.Play$$anonfun$stop$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:107)
> [play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8] [warn] play -  Error stopping plugin
> play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Missing
> configuration [db.default.driver]]    at
> play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
> ~[play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743)
> ~[play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> play.api.db.BoneCPApi.play$api$db$BoneCPApi$$error(DB.scala:271)
> ~[play-jdbc_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]     at
> play.api.db.BoneCPApi$$anonfun$3.apply(DB.scala:298)
> ~[play-jdbc_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]     at
> play.api.db.BoneCPApi$$anonfun$3.apply(DB.scala:298)
> ~[play-jdbc_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
```

Please help.

Comment: Which Play version are you using?

Comment: I upgraded to 2.3.8, if it helps i am also using sbt.version=0.13.7

Comment: Make sure that in your job definition you are using `activator` command and not `play`

Comment: Hi, i was actually using the sbt plugin but downloaded and unzipped activator on the server and tried with activator clean compile test from jenkins. It does not work. If i run it from the shell it works :( I will appreciate any other suggestions, I really want to get this fixed

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3214) similar to yours but for that user it was fixed using `parallelExecution in Test := false`... You may want to comment there or open a new issue. Apart from this the only thing suspicious I see here is the message `Missing configuration [db.default.driver]`

Comment: I have set `db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver` in application.conf and in the hashmap when the fake application is built. The Missing configuration error is gone but the nullpointer is still thrown by NingWSPlugin I guess I will have to open an issue. I will try to reproduce the exception in a test project and then open the issure. Thanks for your help